# Close Main Dialog and show another one as main dialog box,MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

My application (MFC dialog based applocation) has two dialog boxes. The first dialog box is like a login page which should be hidden and instead show another dialog once the login is successful.
I am using the following code to hide the main dialog and display the main window

```
            CDialog:: OnOK();// to hide the login dialog
            mainwindow.DoModal() ;// show the new dialog box
```

My problem here is with my task bar: once I do this, the application is gone from my task bar, but it is present in the CRL+TAB option. How can I make the second dialog window available in the task bar?

Answer (score 1):

[Managing TaskBar Buttons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776822%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#Managing_Taskbar_But) says:

> To ensure that the window button is placed on the taskbar, create an
>   unowned window with the WS_EX_APPWINDOW extended style.